# Getting the most recently edited rows for every member of a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure this must have been asked and answered many times before but I can't find a solution that matches my situation close enough to modify it to work. I think I must just be on an off day as the data I want to retrieve feels like it should be simple and I'm sure I've done similar before on other projects.

I have two tables with data in a bit like the below.

```
t1_id  title
    1  This is the first one
    2  This is another one
```

and

```
t2_id  t2_t1_id  edit_date   content
    1         1  01/02/2020  Some text
    2         2  01/02/2020  Some other text
    3         1  02/02/2020  Some edited text
```

The data I want back from the query should look like this

```
t1_id  title                  t2_id  edit_date   content
    1  This is the first one      3  02/02/2020  Some edited text
    2  This is another one        2  01/02/2020  Some other text
```

So I need one row per `t1_id` and it should be the one with the most recent `edit_date` from the second table.

I have this mostly working with several nested subqueries but it relies on a join on the date column which I don't like and I have one subquery selecting the `max(edited_date)` and grouped on `t2_t1_id` which then joins onto itself to select the remaining data and then joins that onto the first table, so it's a bit of a messy solution and this problem feels like there should be a better one.

This seems like the sort of thing that would be done often enough that there would be a simple, elegant solution for?

Comment: ...which is why it's the most frequently asked question under this tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t2_t1_id order by edit_date desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t2.t2_t1_id = t1.t1_id and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select t1_id, title,t2_id, edit_date, content, 
     row_number() over(partition by t1_id order by edit_date desc) as rn
from table1 t inner join table2 t1 on t.t1_id=t1.t2_t1_id
)A where rn=1
```